# uitableviewcontroller does not show anything

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have storyboard and implement master detail application app ,when i assign manuel class to a tableviewcontroller the objects inside it does not showed and i only get blank table  ,please help.

Comment: Have you defined the tableview as a static or dynamic table view? If it is dynamic you need to set a datasource and give the tableview its data.

Comment: Share some code so we can help you, it's hard to tell what is wrong without code. Check your delegate and datasource maybe they're not set correctly.

Comment: Have you set delegate,and implemented the required method? Post your code so we can help you.

Comment: I defined it as Static Cells and then assign manual class ,I use default code when you add uitbleviewcontroller subclass ,i use the default codes and didn't change the code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS - UITableView not displaying cells](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610155/ios-uitableview-not-displaying-cells)

Comment: As seen in the dupe, delete all datasource methods if you are using static cells.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> “I defined it as Static Cells and then assign manual class ,I use default code when you add uitbleviewcontroller subclass ,i use the default codes and didn't change the code.”

Well of course it’s blank, you’re not giving the table view any data to work with. You need to implement [cellForRowAtIndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView%3acellForRowAtIndexPath%3a) and configure each cell there.

A sample implementation would be:

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView 
    cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

You should read [the table view programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html).

Comment: Static table views should have **no** datasource, or no datasource methods implemented

Comment: Ah, that is right. Is each cell hard-coded in Interface Builder?

Comment: Yes, UITableViewController implements its own datasource methods which I assume read from the storyboard, if you implement your own, it all falls apart