# iOS - UITableView not displaying cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, reuseidentifier

I have the following interface set up in storyboard:

[image]

The controller is a custom controller that extends from UITableViewController. When I run my app this is what I get:

[image]

I thought it might have something to do with the Reuse Identifiers so I changed them to something unique for each of the cells, and modified the code accordingly, but still nothing shows up.

Comment: Provide code of your UITableViewController, it's impossible to help you without it

Comment: Without some code it is quite hard to tell, whats going on. What does you `cellForRowAtIndexPath` look like? This is where the cells are being generated. Or are they static cells? Everythings correctly connected as `IBOutlet` - you see, too many questions open.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you are using static cells in the storyboard, you must **remove** all table view data source methods (number of rows in section, sections, cell for row at index path...) from your table view controller, otherwise the static cells are overridden.

Comment: Me either... this solved an issue I have been working on for 3 days!

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you have positive cell height. I had set the cell height to be zero and was wondering why the heck the cells are not showing.